# Which CUDA runtime DLL is used?

Tags: dll, cuda

I have an application which use CUDA. I am using runtime API and CUDA toolkit 3.2. Application has a dependency on cudart32_32_7.dll. However, there is also cudart32_32_12.dll. The issue is, I do not know how to determine which dll is linked from cudart.lib during the application build. I need to identify dependency dynamically somehow, because I need to include all dependencies into the deployment package. I would like to avoid hard coding dependency path ...

Answer (score 2):

1. Just put the **.dll** or **.exe** of your project into this software: **[Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)**. It will show on what other .dlls yours project depends on. There you'll find either cudart32_32_7.dll or cudart32_32_12.dll.
2. Alternatively, if you're making a binary project. Just compile it and run the binary (.exe) **on a different machine** that doesn't have CUDA installed. An error message will come asking for either cudart32_32_7.dll or cudart32_32_12.dll.

Comment: Yes, I know about Dependency Walker. This is the way I found out which dll is required. But, I would like to know that somehow dynamically or specify via configuration as I want to automate packaging ... I have slightly modified my question to reflect this more clearly. Thanks

Comment: Okay I got your point. I never came up with any solution to figure that out. Ideally your application should use the dll that's shipped with your latest installed toolkit (in this case 3.2). Your PC might have the previous toolkit version files as well, so make sure there's no CUDA path set to those old dlls in your PC's environment variables. (or remove the old files completely)